# Bundling & Minifying Assets in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hey I'm a couple weeks into ASP.NET and .NET in general. I'm having some issues with converting some static pages, specifically with my assets.

I can already tell that I'm doing something silly or just missing something, and I apologize.

I'm trying to bundle all my assets, I'm not sure if this is good practice or not. Coming from a Ruby on Rails background it seemed to make sense at the time.

#### What I've done so far and works:

- All our internal stylesheets and javascripts bundled, minified and served as one file in production.

#### What I was trying to do:

- Bundle all our CDNs and make local copies in our folders.

Here is BundleConfig.cs:

```
// Configuration for bundling CDN content
bundles.UseCdn = true;

// Bundling & Minifying Application wide Stylesheets & JavaScripts
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/application").Include(
    "~/Content/application.css",
    "~/Content/reservations.css",
    "~/Content/accounts.css",
    "~/Content/pets.css"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/application").Include(
    "~/Scripts/application.js",
    "~/Scripts/reservations.js",
    "~/Scripts/pccounts.js",
    "~/Scripts/pets.js"));

// Bundling & Minifying Modernizer
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js").Include(
    "~/Scripts/modernizr-{version}.min.js"));

// Bundling & Minifying JQuery
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js"));

// Bundling & Minifying Font-Awesome
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css").Include(
    "~/Content/font-awesome-{version}.min.css"));

// Bundling & Minifying Bootstrap
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap-{version}.min.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js").Include(
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-{version}.min.js"));

// Bundling & Minifying SweetAlerts
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/sweetalert", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css").Include(
    "~/Content/sweetalert-{version}.min.css"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/sweetalert", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert-dev.min.js").Include(
    "~/Scripts/sweetalert-{version}.min.js"));

// Bundling & Minifying DataTables
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/sweetalert", "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css").Include(
    "~/Content/datatables-{version}.min.css"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/sweetalert", "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js").Include(
    "~/Scripts/datatables-{version}.min.js"));

// Bundling & Minifying Bootstrap-Datepicker
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap-datepicker", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker-{version}.min.css"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap-datepicker", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js").Include(
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker-{version}.min.js"));

// Bundling & Minifying Bootstrap-Switch
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap-switch", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.2/css/bootstrap2/bootstrap-switch.min.css").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap-switch-{version}.min.css"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap-switch", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.2/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js").Include(
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-switch-{version}.min.js"));

// Bundling & Minifying Typeahead.js
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/typeahead", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js").Include(
    "~/Scripts/typeahead-{version}.min.js"));
```

Then in Shared/_Layout.cshtml:

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/font-awesome")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/datatables")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/sweetalert")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap-datepicker")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap-switch")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/application")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatables")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/sweetalert")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap-datepicker")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap-switch")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/typeahead")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/application")
```

Finally is an image of the result:
[image: Webpage result of running the project]

It looks like it's looking for GET localhost:port/bundles/* and cannot find them.

If someone could help me understand what is going on, what I should do/be doing it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify what your trying to do with the CDN files? It sounds like you want asp.net to download the files from the CDN, bundle and minify them, then serve them from the local server? If that is the case that is not the purpose of CDNs and that is not how bundling/magnification works in ASP.Net

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I want to use these CDN. I've read however that ASP.NET doesn't use these in development, so I loaded the project with local copies. I also read that if those CDN were to fail that the server would look for local copies.

Comment: Here is a good site to read over if you have any more questions on Bundling/Magnification:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done is just minifing assets.

You did not bundle them, because you just render each css and js file as single bundle.

In order to bundle, you want to group CSS (or JS) in a single bundle -

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
          ...
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

***FYI:*** You do not want to manify and buindle CND files; it defeats the purpose of caching CDN files at client side. If you want to use **CDNs**, look at [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) article at **Using a CDN** title.

Comment: Hahaha this makes a lot more sense. Thank you!